# LaTeX-Font with all UTF8 symbols defined

Tags: fonts, unicode, font-encodings

I'm writing a program in Java which generates a PDF for something using LaTeX. In this PDF I have to include arbitrary Unicode Characters which I get from a File.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % or \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} for mor characters
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶  · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ 

le\#bla\%dd\@\euro{}i9pi\{\_\}d    dsa ddd4(ozfertig

\char"2200

\end{document}
```

This provides me with a lot of UTF-8-Characters but not all. In the example above the line with `\char"2200` doesn't work everything else does. If I could find a Font which includes every UTF-8-Symbol (even if its just mapped to a ?) this should work. Is there such a font?

If not, is there a document which lists the range of defined Symbols with the packages I am using, such that I can replace the rest with some defined character?

I cannot use XeTeX or LuaTeX, I'm stuck with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: You simply can't use `\char"2200` with pdflatex.

Comment: Is the reason you can't use XeTeX or LuaTeX insurmountable?  Because that seems to be the only way to do what you want to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean Unicode characters rather than UTF-8 characters. Unicode code points are in the range hex 0-10FFFF and pdflatex fonts are restricted to hex 0-FF so you would need thousands of fonts to cover the full Unicode range and a TeX macro definition for each character (or range of characters that can be mapped as a block).

Answer (score 7):

This is something like a hack. If a Unicode symbol definition has been loaded with encodings package such as `textcomp` or options to `fontenc`, with `\UnicodeChar{abcd}` you can access to it, or `?` will be printed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \def\DeclareUnicodeChar#1#2{\global\@namedef{UC@#1}{#2}}
  \def\cdp@elt#1#2#3#4{%
     \lowercase{\InputIfFileExists{#1enc.dfu}{}{}}%
  }\cdp@list
\endgroup
\def\UnicodeChar#1{\@ifundefined{UC@#1}{?}{\@nameuse{UC@#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶  · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ 

le\#bla\%dd\@\euro{}i9pi\{\_\}d    dsa ddd4(ozfertig

\UnicodeChar{2200}

\end{document}
```

[image]